# Determinant of huge matrix Java

Tags: java, matrix, biginteger, determinants, non-recursive

I am making a project in Java where i have to use BigInteger class to implement an encryption method.

I have square matrices nxn where n can be 200 and i need to calculate the determinant. I did the method using the determinant of submatrices but its taking forever to calculate.

```
public BigInteger determinant(Matrix matrix){
    if (matrix.getColumns()!=matrix.getRows()){
        System.out.println("The matrix is not square");
        return BigInteger.valueOf(-1);
    }
    if (matrix.getColumns() == 1) {
    return matrix.getMatrix()[0][0];
    }
    if (matrix.getRows()==2) {
        return ((matrix.getValueAt(0, 0).multiply(matrix.getValueAt(1, 1)))).subtract(( matrix.getValueAt(0, 1).multiply(matrix.getValueAt(1, 0))));
    }
    BigInteger sum = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
    for (int i=0; i<matrix.getColumns(); i++) {
        sum = sum.add(this.changeSign(BigInteger.valueOf(i)).multiply(matrix.getValueAt(0, i)).multiply(determinant(createSubMatrix(matrix, 0, i))));// * determinant(createSubMatrix(matrix, 0, i));
    }
    return sum;
    }
```

Is there a non-recursive way to calculate the determinant?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Computing the determinant is expensive, but is rarely needed. What exactly is the encryption method you are trying to implement?

Comment: Quick answer would be: yes, because everything written recursively can be written non-recursively.

But, are you indeed sure you need to calculate the determinant?

If you really need it, take a look at this package : http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/

Comment: I need to calculate the determinant to make the inverse. plus i need when i create random matrices to make sure they are invertible.

the encryption is a new Fully Homomorphic Encryption. unfortunately i cannot give the paper out in public

Comment: I'm not sure that recursion has anything to do with this being slow...

Answer (score 1):

I've posted this as a comment but I think this could actually solve your problem so I'm posting it as an answer as well.
You can use this package: http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/

Comment: can i use it with BigInteger?

Comment: @OrestisIoannou Seems to work with "double". Are you sure BigInteger is needed?

Comment: Okay well.. As someone formerly stated, are you sure it is the recursiveness making it slow? :P

Comment: hehe well its 200x200 and i need to calculate the determinant i call the method 200! only for the first time... then 200-1  and so on..

Comment: @OrestisIoannou That will be very heavy on your computer even without recursion. As long as you don't get a stackoverflow, and it works.. it seems good. 
Though, you could ask codereview.stackexchange.com for an optimisation of the current algorithm rather than asking a different solution here :)

Answer (score 0):

A common practice of calculating the deterninat of huge matrices is the use an LUP decomposition. In this case, the decerminant can be calculated with following ideas:

```
{L, U, P} = LUP(A)
sign = -1 ^ 'number of permutations in P'
det(A) = diagonalProduct(U) * sign
```

This is how big math packages do that. You should probably implement LU by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is exactly what you need.Using This class you can calculate the determinant of a matrix **with any dimension**

This class uses many different methods to **make the matrix triangular** and then, calculates the determinant of it. It can be used for matrix of high dimension like 500 x 500 or even more. the bright side of the this class is that you can get the **result in BigDecimal** so there is no infinity and **you'll have always the accurate answer**. By the way, using many various methods and avoiding recursion resulted in much faster way with higher performance to the answer. hope it would be helpful.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;


public class DeterminantCalc {

private double[][] matrix;
private int sign = 1;


DeterminantCalc(double[][] matrix) {
    this.matrix = matrix;
}

public int getSign() {
    return sign;
}

public BigDecimal determinant() {

    BigDecimal deter;
    if (isUpperTriangular() || isLowerTriangular())
        deter = multiplyDiameter().multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(sign));

    else {
        makeTriangular();
        deter = multiplyDiameter().multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(sign));

    }
    return deter;
}


/*  receives a matrix and makes it triangular using allowed operations
    on columns and rows
*/
public void makeTriangular() {

    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
        sortCol(j);
        for (int i = matrix.length - 1; i > j; i--) {
            if (matrix[i][j] == 0)
                continue;

            double x = matrix[i][j];
            double y = matrix[i - 1][j];
            multiplyRow(i, (-y / x));
            addRow(i, i - 1);
            multiplyRow(i, (-x / y));
        }
    }
}


public boolean isUpperTriangular() {

    if (matrix.length < 2)
        return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (matrix[i][j] != 0)
                return false;

        }

    }
    return true;
}


public boolean isLowerTriangular() {

    if (matrix.length < 2)
        return false;

    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; j > i; i++) {
            if (matrix[i][j] != 0)
                return false;

        }

    }
    return true;
}


public BigDecimal multiplyDiameter() {

    BigDecimal result = BigDecimal.ONE;
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
            if (i == j)
                result = result.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(matrix[i][j]));

        }

    }
    return result;
}


// when matrix[i][j] = 0 it makes it's value non-zero
public void makeNonZero(int rowPos, int colPos) {

    int len = matrix.length;

    outer:
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            if (matrix[i][j] != 0) {
                if (i == rowPos) { // found "!= 0" in it's own row, so cols must be added
                    addCol(colPos, j);
                    break outer;

                }
                if (j == colPos) { // found "!= 0" in it's own col, so rows must be added
                    addRow(rowPos, i);
                    break outer;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


//add row1 to row2 and store in row1
public void addRow(int row1, int row2) {

    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++)
        matrix[row1][j] += matrix[row2][j];
}


//add col1 to col2 and store in col1
public void addCol(int col1, int col2) {

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
        matrix[i][col1] += matrix[i][col2];
}


//multiply the whole row by num
public void multiplyRow(int row, double num) {

    if (num < 0)
        sign *= -1;


    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
        matrix[row][j] *= num;
    }
}


//multiply the whole column by num
public void multiplyCol(int col, double num) {

    if (num < 0)
        sign *= -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
        matrix[i][col] *= num;

}


// sort the cols from the biggest to the lowest value
public void sortCol(int col) {

    for (int i = matrix.length - 1; i >= col; i--) {
        for (int k = matrix.length - 1; k >= col; k--) {
            double tmp1 = matrix[i][col];
            double tmp2 = matrix[k][col];

            if (Math.abs(tmp1) < Math.abs(tmp2))
                replaceRow(i, k);
        }
    }
}


//replace row1 with row2
public void replaceRow(int row1, int row2) {

    if (row1 != row2)
        sign *= -1;

    double[] tempRow = new double[matrix.length];

    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
        tempRow[j] = matrix[row1][j];
        matrix[row1][j] = matrix[row2][j];
        matrix[row2][j] = tempRow[j];
    }
}


//replace col1 with col2
public void replaceCol(int col1, int col2) {

    if (col1 != col2)
        sign *= -1;

    System.out.printf("replace col%d with col%d, sign = %d%n", col1, col2, sign);
    double[][] tempCol = new double[matrix.length][1];

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        tempCol[i][0] = matrix[i][col1];
        matrix[i][col1] = matrix[i][col2];
        matrix[i][col2] = tempCol[i][0];
    }
}
```

}

And then this class receives a matrix of n x n from the user or can generate a random matrix of nxn and then calculates it's determinant. It also shows the solution and the final triangular matrix.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class DeterminantTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String determinant;

    //generating random numbers
int len = 500;
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
double[][] matrix = new double[len][len];

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = random.nextInt(500);
        System.out.printf("%15.2f", matrix[i][j]);
    }
}
System.out.println();

/*double[][] matrix = {
    {1, 5, 2, -2, 3, 2, 5, 1, 0, 5},
    {4, 6, 0, -2, -2, 0, 1, 1, -2, 1},
    {0, 5, 1, 0, 1, -5, -9, 0, 4, 1},
    {2, 3, 5, -1, 2, 2, 0, 4, 5, -1},
    {1, 0, 3, -1, 5, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2},
    {1, 1, 0, -2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 1, 6},
    {1, 0, 1, -1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 5, 5, 0, 3, 5, 5, 0, 0, 6},
    {1, -5, 2, -2, 3, 2, 5, 1, 1, 5},
    {1, 5, -2, -2, 3, 1, 5, 0, 0, 1}
};

    double[][] matrix = menu();*/

    DeterminantCalc deter = new DeterminantCalc(matrix);

    BigDecimal det = deter.determinant();

    determinant = NumberFormat.getInstance().format(det);

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%15.2f", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("%s%s%n", "Determinant: ", determinant);
    System.out.printf("%s%d", "sign: ", deter.getSign());

}


public static double[][] menu() {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Matrix Dimension: ");
    int dim = scanner.nextInt();

    double[][] inputMatrix = new double[dim][dim];

    System.out.println("Set the Matrix: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%5s%d%n", "row", i + 1);
        for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++) {

            System.out.printf("M[%d][%d] = ", i + 1, j + 1);
            inputMatrix[i][j] = scanner.nextDouble();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    scanner.close();

    return inputMatrix;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The recursive method will take ages to find the determinant of the Matrix of dimension more than 10x10. You will need to do LU decomposition and Gaussian reduction. I used this to find a determinant of 1000x1000 matrix and it produced the correct result within a sec.
You can get this code in Numerical Recipes Book ( use 3rd edition only ): line 52. It is written in C++ but you can easily convert it in Java

or else check **ludcmp()** in this
https://www.cc.gatech.edu/gvu/people/Phd/warren/matrix.c